# ASP.NET MVC 6 project not recognised as web project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm developing a small website and I decided to try ASP.NET MVC 6. I wrote some code on my computer and now I want to test it on the server, first in Visual Studio to debug it. I copied the whole solution folder and pasted on the server, but I cannot run the project. VS complains:

[image]
`The selected debug option is IIS Express but this project is not a web project. To use IIS Express you need to add the wwwroot attribute to project.json.`

Google returns nothing for the error message, which is always a bad sign. Apparently there's a problem with the wwwroot folder, but I don't understand what it's trying to tell me. Note that the wwwroot in the solution explorer is displayed as a normal folder (as opposed to the globe icon I have on my dev machine).

I created the project from the template and everything was working out of the box. Did I miss something when copying the project?

Comment: The error suggests an issue with the wwwroot attribute of the project.json file. Have you confirmed that this attribute exists in your project file?

Comment: No, it does not, but I have the same file on my dev machine and here it works alright.

Comment: Are you running the project in IIS Express or full IIS on your dev machine? The error specifically states it is needed for IIS Express.

Comment: You need to point iis to the wwwroot folder instead of the root of your project.

Comment: I'm running iis express on both.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it. It turns out that ASP.NET 5 runtime was not installed at the server.

Comment: One would assume that the error description would actually know what its talking about. Oh forgot, some things never change! :)